# why is it needed to check the physical device for presentation support after enabling the window extensions like VK_KHR_surface, VK_KHR_win32_surface

Tags: c++, winapi, glfw, vulkan

after enabling the required glfw extensions on vulkan and creating a surface using glfwCreateWindowSurface() function, is it really needed to check whether a physical device supports presentation features as well ( because  we have already enabled the required extensions for understanding window surfaces) , before we choose our physical device to use??

i have come across a code , where they were checking whether a physical device has a queue family which supports presentation features, by using vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR().

```
// Go through each queue family and check if it has at least 1 of the required types of queue
int i = 0;
for (const auto& queueFamily : queueFamilyList)
{
    // First check if queue family has at least 1 queue in that family (could have no queues)

    // Check if Queue Family supports presentation
    VkBool32 presentationSupport = false;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(device, i, surface, &presentationSupport);
    // Check if queue is presentation type (can be both graphics and presentation)
    if (queueFamily.queueCount > 0 && presentationSupport)
    {
        indices.presentationFamily = i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instance extensions for surfaces allow the instance system and compatible drivers to talk to the owner of those surfaces (ie: the operating system). But this does not mean that every physical device actually has a connection to a display. A particular GPU may literally not be plugged into a monitor, which could make direct interactions with displayable images difficult or impossible.

So you have to check to see what a physical device can do with a surface.